# PHP extension (XHProf) installation problems with PHP 5.5.3

Tags: php, configure, php-extension, xhprof

Recently I have upgraded my PHP on Ubuntu 10.04 to the lastest 5.5.3 version, and XHProf profiler stops working.

I have compliled last version of `xhprof` PHP extension (either from official [**pecl** site](http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof) or from [facebook's github repo](https://github.com/facebook/xhprof)), and receive the following message when running `php --version`:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: xhprof: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with build ID=API20121212,NTS,debug
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20121212,NTS
These options need to match
```

So, how to resolve this mismatch?

I have tried `--disable-debug` or `--without-debug` **configure** options configuring XHProf, but **configure** does not understand them.

It is also interesting that `phpinfo` shows the following values:

```
Zend Extension Build     - API220121212,NTS,debug 
PHP Extension Build      - API20121212,NTS,debug 
Debug Build              - yes
```

That is my PHP configure command:

`./configure --enable-opcache --prefix=/opt/php --with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2 --with-mysql=mysqlnd --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-pgsql=/usr --with-tidy=/usr --with-curl=/usr/bin --with-openssl --with-zlib-dir=/usr --with-xpm-dir=/usr --with-pdo-pgsql=/usr --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd --with-xsl=/usr --with-ldap --with-xmlrpc --with-iconv-dir=/usr --with-snmp=/usr --enable-exif --enable-calendar --with-bz2=/usr --with-mcrypt=/usr --with-gd --with-jpeg-dir=/usr --with-png-dir=/usr --with-freetype-dir=/usr --enable-mbstring --enable-zip --with-pear --with-libdir=lib --with-config-file-path=/opt --enable-fpm --with-fpm-user=fpm --with-fpm-group=fpm --enable-debug`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't install Xhprof in PHP 5.4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22630762/cant-install-xhprof-in-php-5-4)