# Can't install Xhprof in PHP 5.4

Tags: php, xhprof

I'm getting the following error when trying to use xhprof in PHP 5.4

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: xhprof: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
```

It looks like I have some conflict with PHP versions as I installed 5.4 some days ago. php-v shows 5.4 but php-config --version shows 5.3 and phpize shows API=20090626 while PHP is compiled with API=20100525

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev
```

In my case the solution was to upgrade the package php5-dev. It looks like when I upgraded php to 5.4  didn't upgrade the php5-dev one, that's why php-config and phpize were outdated. So problem solved.

Comment: what OS and Distro did you have this issue on?
How did you update PHP (not php-dev)? 
There may be a dependency error in your distro's repositories.
If so report it over there.

Comment: Borislav I actually solved my problem. PHP was updated by another person that's why things got messed so much. After updating php5-dev package the problem was fixed. I just posted it in case another people run into this same problem since the other proposed solutions I found on the Internet didn't work in my case. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Correct, you do need to install php5-dev.

This is mentioned in my complete guide to installing XHProf, available here http://www.insprinto.com.au/display/turbocharge-your-php-with-xhprof?id=4